# Not able to connect to Oracle using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am getting below error while trying to connect to Oracle using Sqoop.

ERROR   September 10 2014 1:42 AM   SqoopProtocolServlet

Exception in POST http://bigdatalite.localdomain:12000/sqoop/v1/submission/action/1
org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: GENERIC_JDBC_CONNECTOR_0001:Unable to get a connection
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcExecutor.(GenericJdbcExecutor.java:47)
    at

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin@bigdatalite.localdomain:1521/orcl
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcExecutor.(GenericJdbcExecutor.java:40)

I have kept ojdb6.jar file in /usr/lib/sqoop.
I am using Oracle BigDataLite 2.5

Kindly help to resolve the above issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Jiten Pansara

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi, it looks like sqoop server can not able to reach your Oracle
   server. Please verify that the oracle connection is up and running.
2. If it is running fine, Please validate your connector JAR files are 
   present in Oozie shared lib as well.Since we are using sqoop action in Oozie workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception that you are facing:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc: ...
```

I guess that you did not install Oracle's JDBC driver. If you are using Sqoop downloaded from Apache, then you should install the driver by copying its jar into `lib/` directory ([installation guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html)). Check your distribution installation docs if you are using some of the existing distributions instead. For example per [CDH installation docs](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_sqoop2_configure.html) you should copy it to `/var/lib/sqoop2` if you are using CDH.